# MS BotChat (bot framework) Speech is not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, botframework, speech, web-chat

I am using following article to enable speech, which is working fine in Chrome (even with bing speech).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat-speech?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

However same is not working in Firefox, though it has been mentioned that it should work in Firefox.
I also posted same question here, but havent got a reply, any suggestion?
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1141

Following is the console log of firefox:

```
    This browser does not support speech recognition botchat.js:20:29333
t
https://webchat.botframework.com/scripts/webchat-stable/botchat.js:20:29333
<anonymous>
https://myurl/speechtest/samples/speech/index.html:93:28
This browser does not support speech recognition CognitiveServices.js:15:32927
e
https://webchat.botframework.com/scripts/webchat-stable/CognitiveServices.js:15:32927
<anonymous>
https://myurl/speechtest/samples/speech/index.html:100:27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the js file i was using. As per thread below, I downloaded correct js file and it started working.

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1141

Answer (score 1):

I do a test to enable speech recognition and synthesis in the Web Chat control via Bing Speech service, which can work in both Chrome and Firefox.

[image]

To troubleshoot the issue, you can try:

1) Upgrade your Firefox to the latest version, I'm using Version 62.0

[image]

2) Make sure you allow your site to use your microphone

[image]

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it works on firefox. Though browser is updated and site never asked for micorophone permission. Will do some troubleshooting now.  
Were you able to run this on Internet explorer?

Comment: Based on my test, Currently IE seems not support this. Edge does support it.